# Can't write full text in an Entry - tkinter

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter

I'm working on a GUI software with Tkinter which basically print a general plane of the product after pushing the "Crear" button, as you can see at the following images:

1. GUI Interface

[image]

2. After pushing "Crear" Button

[image]

As you may have appreciated, once you give the full information at the entries and push the "Crear" button, a dynamic table (made with labels and entries in a for cycle) appear with the dimensions of the modules seen at the "Esquema" frame. The problem I have is that, when I edit the information at the dynamic table, I have an immediate change on the graph (which is possible thanks to the trace method) without letting me finish the number I'm already writing; I mean: I can't write the full number at the entries on the dynamic table before it make the changes on the graph. So, my question is: which function or command can I apply to make the program stop and reactivate after I finish writing the full number at the entries on the table?

Any help will be highly appreciated,

PS: I have already tried the "time.stop" and "after" functions. The first one crashed the program, which is unacceptable, and the second one increased the waiting time before I could continue writing numbers at the table. The full code of the program is really extensive, but here I share a runnable code:

## Code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk
from io import open
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
import os, os.path
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#Made by:
#Juan David Argüello Plata

#----------------------------------------------CLASSES AND FUNCTIONS-----------------------------------------------------
class Interface():
    def __init__(self, inter, w=860,h=700, titulo = "Example", titulo_principal = "EXAMPLE"):
        inter.title(titulo)
        inter.resizable(False, False)

        #Dimensions of the screen
        ws = inter.winfo_screenwidth() 
        hs = inter.winfo_screenheight() 

        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

        #Position of the interface
        inter.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        titulo = Label(inter, text = titulo_principal, font=(fuente,24, "bold italic"))
        titulo.pack()

        self.inter = inter

        #---Frames, labels and general data---
        self.Principal_frames()
        self.subframes()
        self.Data()

        #---Actions to execute---
        Action(self)

    def Principal_frames(self):
        self.Frame_Table = Frame(self.inter)
        self.Frame_Table.config(width = "400", height = "600", bd = 2, relief = "groove")
        self.Frame_Table.place(x=10, y=50)

        titulo = Label(self.Frame_Table, text = "Data", font=(fuente,20, "bold italic"))
        titulo.place(x=180, y=5)

        self.Frame_graph = Frame(self.inter)
        self.Frame_graph.config(width = "400", height = "600", bd = 2, relief = "groove")
        self.Frame_graph.place(x=450, y=50)

        titulo = Label(self.Frame_graph, text = "Graph", font=(fuente,20, "bold italic"))
        titulo.place(x=150, y=5)

    def subframes(self):
        self.subframe_Data = Frame(self.Frame_Table)
        self.subframe_Data.config(width = "300", height = "200", bd = 2, relief = "groove")
        self.subframe_Data.place(x=80, y=50)

        self.subframe_graph = Frame(self.Frame_graph)
        self.subframe_graph.config(width = "395", height = "400", bd = 2, relief = "flat")
        self.subframe_graph.place(x=0, y=50)

    def Data(self):
        Length = Label(self.subframe_Data, text = "Length", font = Font)
        Length.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky=W, padx=3)
        self.Length=Entry(self.subframe_Data, width=8)
        self.Length.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=W, padx=3)
        self.Sub_Length=Entry(self.subframe_Data, width=8)
        self.Sub_Length.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=W, padx=3)

        Width = Label(self.subframe_Data, text = "Width", font = Font)
        Width.grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky=W, padx=3)
        self.Width=Entry(self.subframe_Data, width=8)
        self.Width.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W, padx=3)
        self.Sub_Width=Entry(self.subframe_Data, width=8)
        self.Sub_Width.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W, padx=3)

class Action(Interface):
    def __init__(self, inter):
        self.Interface = inter
        self.modification = 0
        Create = Button(self.Interface.subframe_Data, text="Create", font = Font, command = self.Table)
        Create.grid(row=1,column=3)

    def Table(self):
        self.Table = Frame(self.Interface.Frame_Table)
        self.Table.config(width = "150", height = "400", bd=2, relief="groove")
        self.Table.place(x=80, y=150)

        #Dimensions of the labels and entries of the table
        Length = 176
        Width = 200

        #Reading of Data
        self.Data = np.zeros(4)
        self.Data[0] = float(self.Interface.Length.get())
        self.Data[1] = float(self.Interface.Sub_Length.get())
        self.Data[2] = float(self.Interface.Width.get())
        self.Data[3] = float(self.Interface.Sub_Width.get())

        #---Dynamic table ---
        if self.Data[1] > self.Data[3]:
            self.Max = self.Data[1]
        else:
            self.Max = self.Data[3]

        #-Variables-
        label = "label"
        Entry_length = "length"
        Entry_width = "width"
        Numbers_label = [""]*(int(self.Max)+1)
        self.width_data = [""]*(int(self.Max)+1)
        self.length_data=[""]*(int(self.Max)+1)

        self.First_Time = 0    #Counter that depends of the size of the table (help the program to recognize if it's the first time the "Create" button is pressed)
        self.Modules = np.zeros((int(self.Max),2))   #Matrix which contains the table info

        #--Scorllbar--
        self.canvas_table = Canvas(self.Table)
        self.canvas_table.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand = True)
        self.canvas_table.config(width=str(Width), height=str(Length))
        self.Frame_table = Frame(self.canvas_table)
        self.Frame_table.config(width=str(Width), height=str(Length), relief="flat")
        self.canvas_table.create_window(0,0,window= self.Frame_table, anchor = 'nw')

        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(self.Table, orient = "vertical", command = self.canvas_table.yview)
        self.yscroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        self.canvas_table['yscrollcommand'] = self.yscroll.set
        self.Frame_table.bind("<Configure>", self.AuxscrollFunction)
        self.yscroll.grid_forget()


        Number = Label(self.Frame_table, text="", width=4, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove")
        Number.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

        L = Label(self.Frame_table, text="L", width=8, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove")
        L.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

        Wid = Label(self.Frame_table, text="W", width=8, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove")
        Wid.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)

        #Subdivisions (defect values)
        Wth = self.Data[2]/self.Data[3]
        l = self.Data[0]/self.Data[1]

        self.var_length = []
        self.var_width = []
        for i in range(int(self.Max)+1):
            if i != 0:
                Numbers_label[i] = label + str(i)
                Numbers_label[i] = Label(self.Frame_table, text=str(i), width=4, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove")
                Numbers_label[i].grid(row=i,column=0,sticky=W)

                if i <= self.Data[1]:
                    text = str(l)
                else:
                    text = "0.0"

                var_length = StringVar()
                self.var_length.append(var_length)
                self.length_data[i] = Entry_length + str(i)
                self.length_data[i] = Entry(self.Frame_table, width=9, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove", textvariable = self.var_length[i-1])
                self.var1 = self.length_data[i]
                self.var_length[i-1].trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, envio=self: Action.callback(envio))
                self.length_data[i].grid(row=i,column=1,sticky=W)
                self.length_data[i].insert(0, text)

                if i <= self.Data[3]:
                    text = str(Wth)
                else:
                    text = "0.0"

                var_width = StringVar()
                self.var_width.append(var_width)
                self.width_data[i] = Entry_width + str(i)
                self.width_data[i] = Entry(self.Frame_table, width=9, font = Font, bd = 2, relief="groove", textvariable = self.var_width[i-1])
                self.var1 = self.width_data[i]
                self.var_width[i-1].trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, envio=self: Action.callback(envio))
                self.width_data[i].grid(row=i,column=2,sticky=W)
                self.width_data[i].insert(0, text)


        self.yscroll.pack(side='right', fill = 'y')

    def AuxscrollFunction(self,event):
        self.canvas_table.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas_table.bbox("all"))

    def callback(self, *args):
        self.First_Time = self.First_Time+1

        if self.First_Time >= 2*int(self.Max) and self.modification == 0:
            try:
                for i in range(int(self.Max)+1):
                    if i != 0:
                        self.Modules[i-1][0] = float(self.length_data[i].get())
                        self.Modules[i-1][1] = float(self.width_data[i].get())
                self.Data[0] = 0
                self.Data[2] = 0
                for i in range(int(self.Max)):
                    self.Data[0] = self.Data[0]+self.Modules[i][0]
                    self.Data[2] = self.Data[2]+self.Modules[i][1]
                self.Interface.Length.delete(0, 'end')
                self.Interface.Width.delete(0, 'end')
                self.Interface.Length.insert(0, str(self.Data[0]))
                self.Interface.Width.insert(0, str(self.Data[2]))
                #self.var1.focus()
                self.Graph()
            except ValueError:
                pass

    def Graph(self):
    
        #---Area---
        f=Figure(figsize=(3,3), dpi=100)
        a=f.add_subplot(111)

        type_line = 'r--'   #Línea de borde de área
        a.plot([0,self.Data[2]], [0,0], type_line)
        a.plot([0,self.Data[2]], [self.Data[0],self.Data[0]], type_line)
        a.plot([0,0], [0,self.Data[0]], type_line)
        a.plot([self.Data[2],self.Data[2]], [0,self.Data[0]], type_line)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self.Interface.subframe_graph)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=0,y=0)

#--------------------------------------------------------INTERFACE-----------------------------------------------
#---Beginning of the interface---
root = Tk()

#Font
fuente = "TkFixedFont"
Font = (fuente, 10)

Interface(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you need to create minimal (and runnable) example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This might be a user interface design problem.  It's not always possible, or wise, to update a user interface dynamically - especially when the user can type values into fields and change the appearance of something else.  The basic problem is, how does the program know when the user is finished typing or is about to hit another key?  Often it can't.  The user must do something to tell you that he's finished, for example hit the Enter key or click a button.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will make a short example and share it with you.

Comment: For information on creating a short program, see: [mcve], [No mcve](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/), [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/), and Jon Skeet's [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: As I promised, I'm sharing a runnable example (already edited at "Code"). I suggest to use positive integers at the entries. Thank you!

PS: I had noticed that the problem is when I use the graph commands. You can comment the code inside the "Graph" function and replace it with "pass" to see what I'm talking about.